# How to store Protobuf Java model in Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to store objects from a generated Protobuf Java class in a Room database? Do I need to serialize the objects and store the serialized versions inside of an Entity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options. Serialise and save as a Blob (byte[]) or to have Entities that reflect the objects properties and if those are themselves are objects then like wise break them down. This latter approach is potentially more complicated but it does open the data to being more useful database wise.

In short serialise or not to serialise is a choice that would depend upon what is required. Do you just want to use the database for storage or do you want to take advantage of the searchability aspect offered by SQLite (Room).

As an example lets say you have a contract for an address that has the following properties:-

- postbox (int)
- street (string)
- city (string)
- country (string or probably more correctly a reference to a country object)

then if you serialise the object you have a string of bytes (byte[]) and all the data will be stored in a single column.

If you wanted to search for all addresses in a city that would be a) inefficient and also relatively difficult.

If each property were saved in a table with a column per property then that search for the city is straightforward e.g. `SELECT your_columns FROM the_table WHERE city = 'MyCity';`

If the address object were serialised and saved the you might be fortunate and be able to use `SELECT serialised_address FROM the_table WHERE instr(serialised_address,hex('MyCity') > 0;`

- It depends upon how serialisation generates the underlying data

Underneath Room is SQLite and here's a quick SQLite example that demonstrates the difference assuming that the property markers are the property name (e.g. city) followed by = e.g. city MyCity is stored as city=MyCity converted to hex (bytes).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (serialised_address BLOB);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (postbox INTEGER, street TEXT, city TEXT, country TEXT);

INSERT INTO test1 
    VALUES(hex('postbox=1,street="The Street",city="MyCity",country="England"')),
    (hex('postbox=1,street="The Street",city="NotMyCity",country="England"'))
    ;
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(1,'The Street','MyCity','England'),(1,'The Street','NotMyCity','England');

SELECT *,null,null,null FROM test1 UNION SELECT * FROM test2;

SELECT 'S1',serialised_address,null,null,null FROM test1 WHERE instr(serialised_address,hex('MyCity')) > 0
UNION SELECT 'S2',serialised_address,null,null,null FROM test1 WHERE instr(serialised_address,hex('myCity')) > 0
UNION SELECT 'S3',* FROM test2 WHERE city = 'MyCity'
UNION SELECT 'S4',* FROM test2 WHERE city = 'mycity'
;
```

- This creates 2 tables (Entities in Room speak).
- Table test1 is for the serialised object address.
- Table test2 stores the properties in individual columns.
- Both tables are loaded with the equivalent data.
- The first query gets the data from both tables using nulls for the 3 columns that don't exist in the test1 table

  - i.e. all the data is stored in the single column
- The second query looks for the city called MyCity expecting to just extract that 1 city.

When run the results are :-

[image]

(i.e. 2 rows from each table)

and :-
[image]

As you can see 3 rows have been extracted not the expected 2 rows. This is because the search through the byte array for MyCity has also found NotMyCity.